# Как изменить тип данных столбца если таблица заполнена и используется?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть столбец `ID` с числовыми значениями. При создании таблицы, в следствии ошибки проектирования, он был объявлен как `VARCHAR`.

С этим столбцом постоянно возникают проблемы, например, сравнение значений столбца может привести к неожидаемым результатам:

```
select to_number (max (id)) maxid from ( 
    select '9' id from dual union all 
    select '10'   from dual);

     MAXID
----------
         9
```

Есть решение - изменить тип данных столбца:

```
alter table table1 modify id number(10,0);
```

, но оно выдает ошибку:

> ORA-01439: column to be modified must be empty to change datatype

Какой наилучший метод решения этой проблемы?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64352726

Answer (score 5):

Можно реорганизовать таблицу во время её использования с помощью PL/SQL пакета [DBMS_REDEFINITION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_REDEFINITION.html#GUID-2BA796C4-8B4D-49B4-8A35-4C6F789CD374).

Воспроизводимый пример:

```
create table t1 (
    id varchar2 (10) primary key);
create table t2 (
    id number(10,0) primary key);

insert into t1 
    select '9'  from dual union all 
    select '10' from dual;    
commit;

begin 
    dbms_redefinition.start_redef_table ( 
        uname=>user, orig_table=>'t1', 
        int_table=>'t2', 
        col_mapping  => 'to_number (id) id', 
        options_flag => dbms_redefinition.cons_use_rowid);
end;
/
exec dbms_redefinition.sync_interim_table (user, 't1', 't2');
```

При завершении реорганизации, таблица `t1` будет кратковременно заблокирована, а затем она полностью соответствует по структуре таблице `t2`, и последняя может быть удалена:

```
exec dbms_redefinition.finish_redef_table (user, 't1', 't2');

desc t1

Name Null?    Type       
---- -------- ---------- 
ID   NOT NULL NUMBER(10) 

select max (id) maxid from t1;

     MAXID
----------
        10

drop table t2 cascade constraints purge;
```